# Why is my bash array always of length 1 when I split?

Tags: bash, array

```
# Create array
arrayLong=(one two three four)
for element in "${arrayLong[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
echo "${#arrayLong[@]}"
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
four
4
```

Then:

```
# Make new array with only first half of values
arrayShort=("${arrayLong[@]:0:2}")
for element in "${arrayShort[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
echo "${#arrayShort[@]}"
```

The output of this is

```
one two
1
```

Why is my short array not actually an array? It's just one element. How can I split my array when the results are full on arrays?

My bash version is `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`

Comment: It works as it should for me.  Try not quoting arrayLong though, like: `arrayShort=(${arrayLong[@]:0:2})`.  Can you also post the output of: `echo "${IFS@Q}"`

Comment: What's your bash version?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`

Comment: @Jesse_b `echo "${IFS@Q}"` results in the error `${IFS@Q}: bad substitution`

Comment: @teradyl I'm running the same version (under macOS 10.12.5), and I get "2" for the length of arrayShort. Try `declare -p arrayShort` and see what that says (I get `declare -a arrayShort='([0]="one" [1]="two")'`).

Comment: Based on his output I think it's safe to say that his `arrayShort` is `declare -a arrayShort='([0]="one two")'`.  My suspicion is that his `IFS` does not include a space.

Comment: @Jesse_b I also got the `bash: ${IFS@Q}: bad substitution` message. What this command should do?

Comment: @teradyl You can look at the `$IFS` value by this command: `printf "%q\n" "$IFS"` or [others](http://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Show_IFS_value). What output do you get?

Comment: @MiniMax, I'm guessing it's a bashv4.4 thing.  `echo "${var@Q}"` will print the variable as it is quoted so it should look like:  `$' \t\n'`

Comment: Ah that was it! I had changed my IFS before to `IFS=$'\n'` without storing the original value.

Restoring the `IFS` solved the problem. Now my `arrayShort` is properly of length 2.

This is what I get for not reading the full bash tutorial...

@Jesse_b you were right my `IFS` was not the default as you suspected.

@MiniMax Thanks for the `printf` query, the other way with `@Q` was not working for me.

I'll post an answer with the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unaware that `IFS` does not reset automatically after using it. Earlier in the code, I had set the `IFS=$'\n'` without storing the original value. Here's what I should have done:

```
# set Internal Field Separator to new line only to split files
oIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=(${all_files})
# Return IFS to initial value
IFS="$oIFS"
```

To double check what the `IFS` is at a given moment, try `printf "%q\n" "$IFS"`. The default value should be `$' \t\n'`

Thanks @MiniMax & @Jesse_b for helping with this.